# iPhone 4 - TabBar Icons

Tags: iphone, icons, tabbar

How can I set high qualitiy TabBarIcons so it will look nice on the new iPhone 4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a new png resource at the new resolution and append @2x to the filename.  If you are using IB then it should be picked up automatically.  If you are using -imageNamed: then don't include the .png extension on the image name.

For example:  "TabBarIcon.png" would have a "TabBarIcon@2x.png" file that is at double resolution, and will be loaded by UIKit automatically on the iPhone 4.

see [Here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/SupportingResolutionIndependence/SupportingResolutionIndependence.html) for more information.